# Proving $\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int _{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx$ without FTC.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continous function, $g'$ integrable function. Then we have that
$\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int _{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx$.

The proof of this as seen in every calculus/analysis books I have, is by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $$\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx=F(g(x))\big\vert_{a}^{b}=F(x)\big\vert_{g(a)}^{g(b)}=\int _{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx.$$

However, can it be proved without FTC? If we pretend we were living in the age that the FTC hadn't been discovered, we may still can feel that $\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int _{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx$ is true, but how can we prove it?

Comment: You might attempt to prove this, first, when $g$ is a linear function, second, when $g$ is a differentiable Lipschitz function, and third, when $g$ is differentiable where $g'$ is Riemann integrable. Riemann (or Upper and Lower) sums should point the way.

Comment: @Robert By the way, is the proof of change-of-variable formula of multiple integrals somewhat following this way? There seems to be many versions of such proofs, but I have no idea which is more intuitive and straightforward.

Comment: For $f$ continuous, letting $F(y) = \int_0^y f(x)dx= \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f(y\frac{n}{N})$ then $F'(y ) = f(y)$ is not hard to prove, thus not using the  FTC doesn't make any sense. Of course the change of variable formula is then equivalent to $(F(g(x))' = F'(g(x)) g'(x)$, again not hard to prove.

Comment: @reuns It's due to the philosophical reason. First, FTC is somewhat "amazing" and "nontrivial" result in calculus,however,just understanding the much more easy theorem $\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int _{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx$ doesn't necessarily require having known the FTC. Second, in the multiple integral case, the change-of-variable formula $\int_E (f\circ \phi)|\det(\phi')|=\int_{\phi(E)}f$ still holds true. Notice that there is no corresponding idea of FTC in such case, but we still can show that $\int_E (f\circ \phi)|\det(\phi')|=\int_{\phi(E)}f$, can't we? So it suggests the reason I post it.

Comment: Honestly, the only "direct proof" of the change of variable formula I see does reprove the FTC implicitly, by finding some $N,M$ such that the Riemann sums of the two integrals are close to each other. Thus the question really reduces to reproving the FTC. For multi-dimensional change of variables, it works the same way.

Comment: @reuns Hmm.. You say "*the only direct proof of the change of variable I see does reprove the FTC implicitly*", I suppose what you refer to is the proof you had given in your previous comment. But, why is the proof of the change-of-variable formula without FTC must only be your one? Can't it be another?

Comment: The proof via Riemann sums can be easily given if $g'$ is of constant sign. Handling the general case is difficult but requires reasonable search on this website.